# Hibernate Criteria Collection of Objects

Tags: hibernate, orm

I have a class with collection of Objects.
Ex:

```
class XmlRequest{
            Long id;
             List<PersonNmDTO> persons;
     }

class PersonNmDTO{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}
```

I want to generate SQL as follows:
select * from table where (firstname='xxxx' and lastname='yyyy') or (firstname='aaaa' and lastname='bbbb') or  (firstname='pppp' and lastname='qqqq') .......

How to use Hibernate Criteria to generate this kins of SQL?

Answer (score 1):

This is really basic usage. Have you read [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria)?

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Person.class, "person");
Disjunction or = Restrictions.disjunction();
or.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("person.firstName", "xxxx"),
                        Restrictions.eq("person.lastName", "yyyy")));
or.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("person.firstName", "aaaa"),
                        Restrictions.eq("person.lastName", "bbbb")));

// ...
criteria.add(or);
List<Person> result = (List<Person>) c.list();
```

Note that DTO is supposed to mean "data transfer object", which is a mean to transfer data without transferring persistent entities. So naming your persistent entity `PersonNmDTO` is really questionable.

Comment: Disjunction or = Restrictions.disjunction();

Comment: what happens if last name or first name is null or empty string?

Comment: The row won't be found by the query, since it doesnt satisfy the criteria. NULL != xxxx.